# need algorithm to find the nth palindromic number

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

consider that

```
    0 -- is the first
    1 -- is the second
    2 -- is the third
    .....
    9 -- is the 10th
    11 -- is the 11th
```

what is an efficient algorithm to find the nth palindromic number?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I could find an algo to find the nth palindromic number with k digits, for example I could find that the 113th palindromic number with 8 digits is 11122111.

Comment: Use that algorithm and add an iteration over the number of digits.

Comment: @Oswald, agreed. But the OP should also clarify if he needs just an algorithm, or a _quick_ algorithm.

Comment: @Oswald excuse me, can u give an example ?

Comment: ofcourse if a qucik algorithm exists , that'll be better :)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall OP did say "efficient algorithm".

Comment: [Here](http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/12/01/programming-interview-questions-19-find-next-palindrome-number/) are some thoughts on getting the next palindromic number for any number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming that 0110 is not a palindrome, as it is 110.

I could spend a lot of words on describing, but this table should be enough:

```
#Digits #Pal. Notes
   0     1     "0" only
   1     9     x     with x = 1..9
   2     9     xx    with x = 1..9
   3    90     xyx   with xy = 10..99 (in other words: x = 1..9, y = 0..9)
   4    90     xyyx  with xy = 10..99
   5   900     xyzyx with xyz = 100..999
   6   900     and so on...
```

Comment: i guess that's very useful :) tyvm

Answer (score 0):

The (nonzero) palindromes with even number of digits start at `p(11) = 11, p(110) = 1001, p(1100) = 100'001,...`. They are constructed by taking the index `n - 10^L`, where `L=floor(log10(n))`, and append the reversal of this number: `p(1101) = 101|101, p(1102) = 102|201, ..., p(1999) = 999|999, etc`. This case must be considered for indices `n >= 1.1*10^L but n < 2*10^L`.

When `n >= 2*10^L`, we get the palindromes with odd number of digits, which start with `p(2) = 1, p(20) = 101, p(200) = 10001 etc.`, and can be constructed the same way, using again `n - 10^L with L=floor(log10(n))`, and appending the reversal of that number, **now without its last digit**: `p(21) = 11|1, p(22) = 12|1, ..., p(99) = 89|8, ...`.

When `n < 1.1*10^L`, subtract 1 from L to be in the correct setting with `n >= 2*10^L` for the case of an odd number of digits.

This yields the simple algorithm:

```
p(n) = { L = logint(n,10);
         P = 10^(L - [1 < n < 1.1*10^L]); /* avoid exponent -1 for n=1 */
         n -= P; 
         RETURN( n * 10^L + reverse( n \ 10^[n >= P] ))
       }
```

where [...] is 1 if ... is true, 0 else, and \ is integer division.
(The expression `n \ 10^[...]` is equivalent to: `if ... then n\10 else n`.)

(I added the condition n > 1 in the exponent to avoid P = 10^(-1) for n=0. If you use integer types, you don't need this. Another choice it to put max(...,0) as exponent in P, or use `if n=1 then return(0)` right at the start. Also notice that you don't need L after assigning P, so you could use the same variable for both.)